# Angular Google Recaptcha, unexpected token at column 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recaptcha

I am using Angular Google Recaptcha directive from https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha, however when I try to run my application I get the following error: I am using my public key, not my private one. I've tried to add single quotes inside of double quotes, with the same results.

error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '6LflNBo000000000' is an unexpected token at column 2 of the expression [6LflNBo00000000000-0000000000000] starting at [6LflNBo00000000-0000000000000000].

Header:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Footer:

```
  <script  src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit"  async defer ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-recaptcha/3.0.3/angular-recaptcha.min.js"></script>
```

AngularJS:

```
angular.module('main', ['ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'cb.x2js', 'ui.bootstrap', 'vcRecaptcha']).....
```

HTML:

```
<div
   vc-recaptcha
   key="6LflNBo000000000-000000000000000" //key
   ng-model="user.captcha" // --> used for validation>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just put single quotes in your key if you are not using it as a $scope variable.

It will be like that:

```
<div
  vc-recaptcha
  key="'6LflNBo000000000-000000000000000'" //key
  ng-model="user.captcha" // --> used for validation>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the single quotes.

Comment: @Coded-Container, Do you not want to accept his answer?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and it seems the demo code from that github entry is either outdated or not correct. What I did was I went directly to the demo site: http://vividcortex.github.io/angular-recaptcha/

The entire angularjs and recaptcha code is working on that page so you can just view source from a working live demo version. It worked for me.